# How do you provide xml comments/documentation for delegate parameters?

Tags: c#, delegates, comments

given a delegate like

```
Func<string,string,string> MyFunc = (firstName,lastName) => string.Format("Given Name:{0} Surname:{1}",
                                                                            firstName,
                                                                            lastName);
```

How would you can you document the parameters of firstName and lastName, so they show up in intellisense (like method descriptions and parameters do)?
Example:

```
/// <summary>
/// My Method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="firstName">The first name.</param>
/// <param name="lastName">The last name.</param>
/// <returns></returns> 
public string MyMethod(string firstName, string lastName)
{ 
  return string.Format("Given Name:{0} Surname:{1}",firstName,lastName);
}
```

I want to hover over the delegate or have intellisense popup when I type and tell me the descriptions for the the delegate parameters, like it would with the above method.

Comment: To me, it seems strange to document an anonymous function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A field of a delegate type is still a field and not a method—it doesn't take parameters in itself. The parameters belong to the delegate *type*, not the delegate *field*. You can write the comments for parameters when you delegate types if you want.

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests something.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="test">Something that's going to be tested.</param>
delegate void Test(int test);
```

`Func<string,string,string>` is a general delegate for functions with three parameters. For specific purposes, you can always declare your own delegate type that represents the abstracted method more specifically and add comments to its parameters.

Comment: It's too bad there isn't some way to provide documentation that intellisense will pick up on for a `Func<string,string,string>` In many cases the function to be assigned to such a declared variable is expected to performs specific duties and there are specific expectations about what is being passed in and what is being returned.